# How can I change gRPC's reconnection behaviour in the Node.js implementation?

Tags: node.js, grpc

From what I can tell, the gRPC client automatically attempts to reestablish lost connections using a backoff algorithm. My goal is for gRPC to instead attempt reconnection at least every second.

Using the Go implementation this is possible by passing the [`WithBackoffMaxDelay`](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc#WithBackoffMaxDelay) dial option when first establishing the connection to the service. How can I do the same in the Node.js implementation?

---

As suggested I tried passing the `grpc.max_reconnect_backoff_ms` option to the client constructor. If I deliberately pass an invalid value like -1, gRPC logs an error message, so I believe I'm using it correctly.

However, the option doesn't seem to affect gRPC's reconnection behaviour. Instead it appears to attempt reconnection roughly every 20s:

```
I0215 21:21:07.246695000 140736304567232 subchannel.c:694] Connect failed: {"created":"@1487190067.246665000","description":"Failed to connect to remote host","errno":61,"file":"../src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_client_uv.c","file_line":104,"os_error":"connection refused"}
I0215 21:21:07.246910000 140736304567232 subchannel.c:491] Retry in 19.999536519 seconds
```

Even more confusing, gRPC doesn't seem to use a backoff algorithm at all, i.e. it always uses the ~20s value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue, and after investigating the gRPC core source (in C), I've understood the problem:

- It's possible to configure the max time, as pointed by @murgatroid99, however, isn't possible to configure the min time, which is forced to be 20 seconds.

I've made a Pull Request at the gRPC repository, for making it configurable:
https://github.com/grpc/grpc/pull/10237

If you use the branch from my fork, you'll be able to do this at your client constructor:

```
new ...client(host, credentials, {
  'grpc.min_reconnect_backoff_ms': 1000,
  'grpc.max_reconnect_backoff_ms': 10000,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The Node gRPC Client constructor takes an optional third argument with options for the underlying implementation. One of those options is `"grpc.max_reconnect_backoff_ms"`. As the name suggests, the value is in milliseconds, so you should pass 1000 as the value.

Comment: Thank you for the speedy reply! Your answer brought me a step closer but unfortunately hasn't solved the problem yet. I've updated the question with some more information.

Comment: @murgatroid99 See my answer, please!